# Headless graphics adapter for CentOS with OpenGL support? (Or similar blade server device?)

Tags: linux, graphics-card, centos

I have two Linux applications that require a frame buffer that can support OpenGL calls (R and Processing).

I have tried virtual/software frame buffers like Xvfb, but they do not support the OpenGL calls that either application makes. So I am unable to capture correct video output from R or Processing without using a device, so far, with a dedicated adapter.

I'd like to ask our system administrator to add a graphics adapter to one of our blade servers running CentOS. Adding an internal PCIExpress or other internal bus card is not likely, due to hardware limitations. I also cannot expect to be able to connect a physical display.

Are there "headless" USB display adapters I could use with such a setup, which will provide reasonably modern OpenGL support without requiring a connected display?

Failing that, are there blade servers that offer modern graphics support, such as perhaps hardware that computer animation shops would use to headlessly automate rendering 3D graphics?

I'm already using a laptop on my desk as a workaround, so I'm not so much interested in hacking together a solution in that direction, but I am looking for something I can ask our IT people to integrate with their server room and general setup.

Comment: See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137567/glx-extension-not-working-properly-with-xvfb) for using GLX (Mesa) together with Xvb/Xdummy. Mesa is a complete software renderer anyway, so you shouldn't need extra hardware (USB or otherwise).

Comment: @dirkt do you have ideas for a similar setup which also supports hardware acceleration?

Comment: @Edward not sure what you mean: you want hardware acceleration without the hardware (graphics cards) that does the acceleration? You *can* support OpenGL with software, but you can't really do hardware acceleration without the hardware. You can run a headless X server with a graphics card, though, just with the normal driver. Please make a new question, and describe the details.

Answer (score 0):

My guess you're formula is somewhat wrong.

Purely headless (without any GPU / VGA adapter) solutions cannot provide any "native" OpenGL support, as the word "native" means GPU-handled, vs. CPU-handled stands for "software" emulation.

It has nothing to do with "display attached" vs headless boxes / servers this way; server can run nicely without any VGA display or adapter connected for years.

My guess is, your case is about proper configuration of GPU/VGA drivers (to support one installed into you server), then sharing 'the picture' to remote client.

Most likely the primary reason you hit this is lack of corresponding kernel modules (aka drivers in MSWin) for particular adapter you use

Comment: By headless, I mean specifically having a working frame buffer that offers OpenGL support without a physical display connected. There is no graphics adapter in the server — I can only SSH in. Thanks.